# $\int_{1/2}^1t^{{1\over f(x)}-3} \sin t^2dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I got this integral $\int_{1/2}^1t^{{1\over f(x)}-3} \sin t^2dt$ (note: $t$ is raised to the ${1\over f(x)}-3$ in case its hard to see.) I am really struggling to find the answer to this, I'm not even really sure how to approach it

---

The original question was $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \int_{1/2}^1t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)$ we also know that $f$ is a real function with $f(0)=0 ,$continuous and  differentiable for $x \neq0 $ and $f'(x)= \frac{e^x}{3f^2(x)+2f(x)+1}$. There also exists a $x_0, 0<x_0<2 $ s.t. $f(x_0)=1$. I have found : $f^3(x)+f^2(x)+f(x)=e^x-1$ , $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0)=1$, $\int_0^{x_0} e^xf(x)= {{23\over 12}} $ Although I am not sure how many of these will be needed.

---

EDIT: I am aware of the solution by DTC but I was hoping to find a "simpler" (lack of a better word) one if possible , any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: For example the integral $$\int sin(x^2) dx$$ is not elementary, so it is quite possible this one is too

Comment: Any other assumptions on $f$? Is it continuous? Differentiable?

Comment: I used that word for a lack of better terminology. I meant that I think it would be less "advanced" to evaluate the integral first and then the limit

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes , I thought they would not be needed that is way I did not put them in the original post, I have now edited it to include all the details that were given/I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see that $3x^2+2x+1 = 2x^2 + (x+1)^2 >0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and so $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So $f$ is strictly increasing and in particular $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Furthermore, $|\sin(t)| \leq |t|$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and in particular for $0\leq t\leq \pi$ we have $0\leq \sin(t)\leq t$. So for $t\in [1/2, 1]$ we get
$$0\leq t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)\leq t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\cdot t^2 = t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-1}$$

Integrating both sides from $1/2$ to $1$ we get
$$0\leq \int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)\,dt\leq f(x)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)$$

Finally, notice that $1/f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ and so the limit of the RHS is equal to $0$. From the squeeze theorem, we get
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_{1/2}^1 t^{\frac{1}{f(x)}-3}\sin(t^2)\,dt=0$$